# Class functions lose context when they are passed into an express router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, this

I recently wrote a small access control module for an application.  The back-end is node with express.  The module is as follows

```html
class Rbac {
  constructor() {
    if (!Rbac.instance) {
      Rbac.instance = this;
    }
    this.rbacStructure = {};
    this.init = this.init.bind(this);
    this.checkPermission = this.checkPermission.bind(this);
    this.checkPermissionSync = this.checkPermissionSync.bind(this);
    this.checkPermissionMiddleware = this.checkPermissionMiddleware.bind(this);
    this.doesPermissionExistInGroup = this.doesPermissionExistInGroup.bind(
      this
    );
    this.instance = this;
    return Rbac.instance;
  }
  
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  
const instance = new Rbac();

Object.freeze(instance);

export default instance;
```

In my app.js I want to pass the instance of the object to a router as follows

```html
import Rbac from "./helpers/rbac";
import settingRouteExport from "./routes/settingRoutes";

const settingsRoutes = settingRouteExport(Rbac);
app.use("/settings", settingsRoutes);
```

And I'm trying to use it in the settingRoutes as follows

```html
import express from "express";
const router = express.Router();
// Exporting the function that returns the router
export default (Rbac) => {
.
.
.
.
.
  router.get(
    "/users",
    Rbac.checkPermissionMiddleware(["canCreateUser", "canEditUser"]),
    UserControllers.getUsers
  ); 
.
.
.
.
.
  return router;
};
```

Even though I bound the class functions to object, I keep getting the error below

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'checkPermissionMiddleware' of undefined
```

If I import the module directly into the route everything works as expected, I just want to know why my class functions lose context even though I bind them in the constructor.  Is there any way of preventing this?

Comment: What is the `export default Rbac`? Please share the complete code, it's not clear what you are doing.

Comment: Oh sorry, that is the settingsRoutes file, I'll edit the question to make it clearer

Comment: @Marlom yes that comes from the instance of Rbac, I already have access to the instance in app.js, I just wanted to pass it into a router

Comment: Don't use a `class` if you only need a single object.

Comment: @Bergi That does make sense, but this approach should technically work as well.

Comment: @Bergi worst case, I'm going to scrap the class and write it as an object

Comment: Can you show us how you import `Rbac` in the file where you call `settingRouteExport(Rbac);`?

Comment: I suggest you create a simple ES6 class with a single function with similar conventions to debug your problem. Don't pass it into express, just pass it into another function that calls the single method.

Comment: @Bergi IT is a simple import,  import Rbac from "./helpers/rbac".  I'm also going to update the code above to show the import

Comment: @powerup7 I'm going to try to write a small application as you said, will post the results

Comment: Hm, looks fine. Do you have any circular dependencies?